# ASP.NET Core 2 - global filters registration multiple ways?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

What is the difference in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method between:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

and

```
 services.AddMvc(config=> 
 { 
     config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); 
 });
```

Aren't these two equivalent?

Comment: yes,there are multiple ways to do one thing sometimes, like in Owin there are multiple ways to set the startup class and method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those are essentially the same. Depending on the options and values being set, one might override the other, but they still achieve the same thing.